# Create an array with names from multi arrays that unique

Tags: javascript

For example I have an array like this

```
var arr = [
    ['Red', 'Black'],
    ['S', 'M'],
    ['Cotton', 'Linen']
]
```

How to have the result with an array likes:

```
result: [
   'Red - S - Cotton',
   'Red - M - Cotton',
   'Red - S - Linen',
   'Red - M - Linen',
   'Black - S - Cotton',
   ...
]
```

This is the code I coded before, but it not work as I want :( the result is not good as I want https://jsfiddle.net/minhthe208/shkz7av3/47/ (please see the console, it's duplicated name) and miss some names, for example: Black - M - Cotton is missed

```js
    var arr = [
          ['Red', 'Black'],
          ['S', 'M'],
          ['Cotton', 'Linen']
        ]
        
        var sum = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          sum *= arr[i].length;
        }
        
        function FullRow(arr, len) {
          var index = 0
          var result = []
          var current = 0
          while (index < len) {
            if (current === arr.length)
              current = 0
            result[index] = arr[current]
            index++
            current++
          }
          return result
        }
        
        function Combine(arr, len) {
          var result = arr[0];
          for (var index = 1; index < arr.length; index++) {
            for (var current = 0; current < len; current++) {
              result[current] += ' - ' + arr[index][current];
            }
          }
          return result;
        }
        
        var combineArr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          combineArr.push(FullRow(arr[i], sum));
        }
        
        console.log('----COMBINE----')
        var finalArr = Combine(combineArr, sum)
        
        console.log(finalArr)
```

What should I do to have the result as above?

Comment: Post your code here.

Comment: @possum the forum didn't allow me do this, please go to the jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/minhthe208/shkz7av3/49/

Comment: No.  You shouldn't assume people are willing to click through to a different site to help you.  If you are not able to post the code here for some reason, then you need to address that problem.

Comment: @possum thanks, finally I can edit the post. please see my code above

Comment: Will you always have 3 sub-arrays?

Comment: @Cid Hi Cid, No, it's just an example. It may changed depend on the user input

Comment: See [How can I create every combination possible for the contents of two arrays?](/q/8936610/4642212).

Comment: @SebastianSimon thanks for your reply, but my problem is really difference situation. 1) I'm not sure how much sub array in the parent array, and 2) every arrays not the same length

Comment: @ThiếtKếWebsiteMinhThế The first point is not an issue: at least one answer there covers the case of an “arbitrary number of arrays”. The second point shouldn’t be an issue either, but it depends on what you plan to do with mismatching array lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const array = [
  ["Red", "Black"],
  ["S", "M"],
  ["Cotton", "Linen"],
];

const result = (...a) =>
  a.reduce((a, b) => a.flatMap((d) => b.map((e) => `${d},${e}`)));

let output = result(...array);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: You're really at a difference level with mine, wish that one day I could do the same and could be the logic as you. Thanks you @Bimal Pariyar